24.04 disconnects from vpn after a few minutes
I've recently upgraded my laptop to 24.04 and I started to experience the following issue.
I use a VPN connection (OpenVPN server) to work remotely and after the OS upgrade the connection hangs after a few minutes (3-5). When I start the vpn conection I can log into the remote servers (ssh, vs-code) and can work during 3-5 minutes. After that, the connection hangs and the vpn is not longer available. If I stop and restart the vpn client "sometimes" the terminal continue working (not always). Just to be clear, it worked perfectly on 22.04 previous to the SO upgrade.
I've seen some issues with DNS entries (resolv.conf) and I tried the suggestions but could not solve the issue.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
Here's a syslog dump
oct 02 08:31:17 chevy NetworkManager[1062]: <info>  [1727868677.0577] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (c2030cc9-ebbe-45b6-9ded-e92ef2cf860d)
oct 02 08:31:17 chevy NetworkManager[1062]: <info>  [1727868677.0643] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
oct 02 08:31:17 chevy NetworkManager[1062]: <info>  [1727868677.0659] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
oct 02 08:31:17 chevy NetworkManager[1062]: <info>  [1727868677.0670] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
oct 02 08:31:17 chevy NetworkManager[1062]: <info>  [1727868677.0691] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
oct 02 08:31:17 chevy NetworkManager[1062]: <info>  [1727868677.1593] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
oct 02 08:31:17 chevy NetworkManager[1062]: <info>  [1727868677.1619] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
oct 02 08:31:17 chevy NetworkManager[1062]: <info>  [1727868677.1699] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
oct 02 08:31:27 chevy systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
oct 02 08:31:37 chevy wpa_supplicant[1064]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-60 noise=9999 txrate=240000
oct 02 08:33:50 chevy systemd[2483]: Started app-gnome-org.gnome.Terminal-7155.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
oct 02 08:33:50 chevy systemd[2483]: Started vte-spawn-dce2ade2-46d3-4a54-b410-000a10e4ec9a.scope - VTE child process 7163 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 6014.
oct 02 08:34:17 chevy systemd[1]: anacron.service - Run anacron jobs was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionACPower=true).
oct 02 08:35:01 chevy CRON[7269]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
oct 02 08:35:01 chevy CRON[7270]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
oct 02 08:35:01 chevy CRON[7269]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
oct 02 08:35:14 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: [vpn_2024] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
oct 02 08:35:14 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
oct 02 08:35:15 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
oct 02 08:35:15 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]170.210.96.2:21194
oct 02 08:35:15 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
oct 02 08:35:15 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]170.210.96.2:21194
oct 02 08:35:16 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: [vpn_2024] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]170.210.96.2:21194
oct 02 08:35:16 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
oct 02 08:35:16 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: tun0
oct 02 08:35:16 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: /usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --debug 0 6976 --bus-name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn.Connection_16 --tun -- tun0 1500 0 172.25.103.14 255.255.0.0 restart
oct 02 08:35:16 chevy dbus-daemon[986]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.158" (uid=121 pid=7275 comm="/usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --d" label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Plugin" member="SetConfig" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.156" (uid=0 pid=6976 comm="/usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service --bus-name org.fre" label="unconfined")
oct 02 08:35:16 chevy dbus-daemon[986]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.158" (uid=121 pid=7275 comm="/usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service-openvpn-helper --d" label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.VPN.Plugin" member="SetIp4Config" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.156" (uid=0 pid=6976 comm="/usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service --bus-name org.fre" label="unconfined")
oct 02 08:35:16 chevy nm-openvpn[6987]: Initialization Sequence Completed
oct 02 08:35:24 chevy wpa_supplicant[1064]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-57 noise=9999 txrate=0


You'll have to look at your logs. I think by default network/VPN logging will go to /var/log/syslog but it will depend on your config. Take a look there around the dates/times the VPN disconnects and see if there are any clues. Update your original question with log excerpts (properly formatted as code sample etc). Personally I have had no issues with OpenVPN in 24.04
